# Colorings of a set

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a problem which goes as follows:

Consider a finite set $V$ and a collection $F=\{F_1,F_2,...,F_m\}$ of $n$-subsets where $n\ge4$. Prove that if $m<\frac{4^{n-1}}{3^n}$ then there exists a $4$ coloring of $V$ such that all $F_i$'s contain all $4$ colors.

General strategy:

Firstly if we let $\Omega = \{\text{set of all 4 colorings of V}\} $ then we get that $|\Omega|=4^{|V|}$ since there are $4$ choices of colors. Then if we take $A_i=\{\text{all colorings of}\space F_i\space \text{that use at most 3 colors}\}$, we want $P(\bigcup A_i) < 1$ (where $P(\text{some event})$ is the probability of that event occurring) which would imply that such a good coloring exists. I'm having trouble finding $|A_i|$. How would I find this value?

Comment: You want $A_i$ to be the set of all colorings that use at most $3$ colors for the elements of $F_i$, not those that use just one color for those elements. Only then does being in the complement of $A_i$ ensure that the requirement relative to $F_i$ (namely using all four colors) is met.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Yes you're right. I've corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You talk about probabilities without having defined a distribution; I take it that you're trying to apply the probabilistic method by colouring each element of $V$ with one of the $4$ colours with equal probabilities.

There's no need to find $|A_i|$, you just need a bound for it. To see what bound you need, you can work backwards from the target bound: The expected number of inadmissible colourings is $\sum_i|A_i|/4^n=m|A_1|/4^n$, so for this to be $\lt1$ when $m\lt4^{n-1}/3^n$ you need $|A_1|\lt4\cdot3^n$. Can you see why that bound holds?

(In fact it's not too difficult to determine $A_i$ using [inclusion–exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), but why make things harder than they are...)

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. One minor problem: shouldn't it be |A1|<=4*3^n instead of just <? And is the rest of the solution like: 4*3^n = (4 choose 3)*3^n, therefore.....?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm right or not but $|A_i| = 4 \cdot 4^{|v|-n} \cdot 3^n$

Comment: That's the number of colourings of $V$ in which $F_i$ is coloured with at most three colours; but $A_i$ is the set of all colourings of $F_i$ that use at most three colours.